# android child view no press state

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-layout, view

I have made a linear layout on which I am adding views, simulating a table because I have read that a listview inside a scrollview is not an option :)
So I have a linear layout with wrap_content inside a scrollview.

The problem is that for the views I am adding I can't trigger any press state to change the graphics as before when it was in the listview it worked great.

I have the following:

```
    if (arrayWorksWith.size()!=0)
    {
        this.listAdapter = new WorksWithListAdapter(this, R.layout.works_with_cell, R.id.lblItemTitle, arrayWorksWith);

        for (int i=0; i<arrayWorksWith.size(); i++)
        {
            View v = this.listAdapter.getView(i, null, layoutTblWorksWith);
            v.setTag(new Integer(1000 + arrayWorksWith.get(i).getId()));
            v.setOnClickListener(this);

            layoutTblWorksWith.addView(v);
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the click event gets fired but I don't have any visual feedback. Inside that view I have an Imageview with the background set to the following drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">     

<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/r1" /> <!-- pressed -->     
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/r1" /> <!-- focused -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/transparent_background" /> <!-- default --> 

</selector>
```

Also I have just tried a touch listener on the view I am adding, but this fails as well :(

```
                v.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
                {
                     public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event)
                     {
                         TextView lblCategoryTitle = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.lblItemTitle);                       

                         if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                         {
                             lblCategoryTitle.setTextColor(R.color.white);
                         }
                         else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                         {
                             lblCategoryTitle.setTextColor(R.color.textLabel_blue);
                         }

                         return false;
                     }
                });
```

So when this code was inside a ListView when I tapped on a cell the image was changing the background giving visual feedback, but when I am creating it now and adding it to a LinearLayout it stopped working.

Any ideas? I have tried playing with focusable, clickable, duplicate parent state, but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the listView on to an OnItemClickListener, not on an OnClickListener.